# Can I say "graphic design is my passion so you are"?

Tags: phrase-choice

I want to say this in a shorter way:

> graphic design is my passion and you are my passion too

Can I say either of these?

- graphic design is my passion, so you are.
- graphic design is my passion, just like you.

Both seemed okay, but Google Translate translated it something like "graphic design is my passion just like it's your passion too."

Comment: It is an odd thing to say. It is kind of rude to say to a boy/girlfriend that they are no more special than your job or hobby.

Comment: Don't be too dismayed at Google Translate giving unexpected results. It's only the very broadest starting point in bridging a language gap.

Comment: You need to look up: so [auxiliary verb] [subject]. Also, with nor/neither. This will make your English more fluent.

Comment: Note that using _and so you are_ without the inversion, it will be read as containing the expression _and so_ = _and therefore_. It doesn't make a lot of sense, but the meaning you want did not even occur to me when I read it.

Comment: If I was making a "graphic design is my passion" mug, I might want the broken English of "so you are" :P

Comment: Grammatically, you might get away with various versions, as illustrated.

Idiomatically, you have no chance.

D'you not have a tutor/mentor/colleague to help with such queries?

Comment: Despite the Answers below, how could that phrase actually work in English? If it's a direct translation from any other language still, the translation won't work in English.

The closest you could really get might be 'Graphic design is my (greatest) passion, after you…' and that meaning is very different.

Comment: You may want the broken English? Are you writing dialogue for a non-native English speaker?

Answer (score 13):

With the warning that it is slightly rude (but this might be the joke).

You need to invert the subject and verb in the second clause

> Graphic design is my passion, and so are you.

Inversion is necessary in clauses with "So" or "Neither" "I don't play the piano, neither does Jack", I play the piano, so does Jack".

Comment: It works as a [paraprosdokian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian).

Answer (score 6):

Given the context that this is supposed to be written on a humorous mug for your boyfriend, I think the best way to say this would be:

*Graphic design is my passion... and so are you!*

It retains the original meme, and reframes the "deprioritization" of your partner as more of a "surprise at the end" type of thing.

It's definitely postcard-tier script, but it's entirely functional toward your goal without any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

My two passions are graphic design, and you!.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't want to change the part "graphic design is my passion" since it's from a meme :D for context this is for a funny mug design for my boyfriend.

Comment: @sümeyyeTheGmc, this context is really helpful! If you mention the meme and the mug in your question, I think you'll get better answers.

Comment: @sümeyyeTheGmc I've just looked up the meme, and I think it's obligatory that you comic sans and a rainbow colored font, btw. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would personally prefer this on a mug; a variant of James K's answer:

> Graphic design is my passion, as are you!

The reason I like it more is because I feel it links the two statements more directly. Coupling them with "and" gives the impression of a looser connection in my opinion, as if they are more analogous than directly related, but that's a highly subjective assessment.

Something more close to your original suggestion would be:

> Graphic design is my passion, just like you are!

Comment: "as are you" was my immediate first thought too. I think it's the most natural and idiomatic way to say it. It also wraps the sentence in nouns, which makes it more poetic I think